# Rotate Array using erase function in vectors

Tags: arrays, sorting

Problem statement: Given an integer array nums, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.

My sol.:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    void rotate(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        int n = nums.size();
        k=k%n;
        for(int i=0;i<=k;i++){
            nums.push_back(nums[i]);
        
        }
        nums.erase(nums.begin(),nums.begin()+k+1);
    }
};
```

I am using `push_back()` function to push the starting k element to end and then `erase()` function to clear the starting k elements. but it's not working for all the test cases.
eg:

```
Your input
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
k=3
[-1,-100,3,99]
k=2
Output
[5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
[99,-1,-100,3]
Expected
[5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
[3,99,-1,-100]
```

Can anyone help where I am wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are rotating in the wrong direction ... *"Rotate right"* means remove from the back and insert at the begin. You are doing it vice versa, ie remove from the beginn and insert at the end.

Furthermore you are rotating one time to many. Because of this off-by-one error your first example seems to work. But that's just a coincidence because rotate left 4 times equals rotate right 3 times in a 7 element vector.

```
void rotate(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
  int n = nums.size();
  k=k%n;
  for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
    nums.insert(nums.begin(), nums.back());
    nums.pop_back();
  }
}
```